# Nginx redirect to different domain keep request_uri

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, http-headers, uri

I wish to redirect user from my domain `www.domain.com/abc/`,
To a survey on `google docs` and **keep my domain url in browser**.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
location ~ /abc/ {
        1 return 301  https://docs.google.com/forms/abcdefg?usp=sf_link;
        2 set $cleanuri $uri;
        3 return 301 docs.google.com/forms/abcdefg?usp=sf_link;
        4 proxy_set_header X-Rewrite-URL $request_uri;
        5 proxy_set_header X-Rewrite-FullURI $request_uri;
        6 proxy_set_header X-Rewrite-CleanURI $cleanuri;
}
```

line 1: tried to return url with line 4 `proxy_set_header` with `request_uri`.
line 2: saved `uri` to use with lines 3, 5, 6 to preserve original url in browser.
(hope this makes sense).
No combination worx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use http://nginx.org/r/return here, neither `301` nor any other code, and http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header all by itself doesn't do anything.

You have to either use http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass or HTML5 `iframe`:

- Doing `proxy_pass` against `docs.google.com` might cause problems with too many requests coming out of a single IP address into Google Docs, which might prompt them to blacklist your IP address, and/or start giving your users captcha images to solve; it might also trigger various cross-site scripting, pfishing and hotlink protections on Google's end as well, and interfere with user authentication due to `google.com` cookies missing from the request; in short, this is probably not supported by Google.
- Likewise, the HTML `iframe` approach is pretty much dead nowadays, due to what is known as Clickjacking, where `X-Frame-Options` might prevent you from doing this embedding.

In short, what you want to do is unlikely to be supported by Google Docs.  Even if you do manage to make it work, it'll likely get broken rather quickly.

Comment: can you give an example implementation of `proxy_pass`?

Comment: @Jadeye `location = /abc { set $google_docs https://docs.google.com/forms/abcdefg?usp=sf_link; proxy_pass $google_docs; }`.  You might also have to specify a resolver with http://nginx.org/r/resolver, and `X-Forwarded-For` header, too; but, regardless, with all the JavaScript that Google Docs is likely to be using, this is all highly unlikely to work in practice; not to mention that you'll be interfering with user authentication, too.